# Finding the temperature of a product using Newton's Law of cooling

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am working on a problem to predict the temperature of a particular product kept inside a refrigerator using Newton's Law of cooling. I am trying to do this using the first 3 temperature reading of ambient (temperature of air inside the refrigerator) and product temperature. I have setup an experiment measure the temperature of a particular product and ambient temperature at the same time. The temperature of ambient and product is available every 5 mins and the temperature is measured in Celsius. This experiment is conducted in a very controlled environment using a very accurate thermometer and refrigerator. The temperature readings are as below:

---

| Datetime | Ambient Temperature | Product Temperature |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 28-08-2017 00:01 | 4 | 3.69 |
| 28-08-2017 00:06 | 4.63 | 3.56 |
| 28-08-2017 00:11 | 4.81 | 3.5 |
| 28-08-2017 00:16 | 5.13 | 3.63 |
| 2017-08-28 00:21 | 5.44 | 3.75 |
| 2017-08-28 00:26 | 5.63 | 3.88 |
| 2017-08-28 00:31 | 5.13 | 4 |
| 2017-08-28 00:36 | 4.75 | 4 |
| 2017-08-28 00:41 | 4.5 | 3.88 |
| 2017-08-28 00:46 | 4.25 | 3.69 |
| ------------------------------------------------------------ |  |  |

This is how I have tried to solve the problem
I am considering the 1st reading as t = 0, 2nd reading as t = 5, 3rd reading as t = 10 and so on ….

t - time period

Ta(1) - temperature of the ambient at t = 0

Ta(2) - temperature of the ambient at t = 5

T(1) - temperature of the product at t = 0

T(2) - temperature of the product at t = 5

Newton's Law of cooling = $\frac{dT}{dt} = −k(T−Ta)$

This can also be written as: $T = Ta + C * e^{-kt}$

I have to calculate 'C' which is the initial temperature and 'k' which is the cooling/ heating constant

At t = 0,

$3.69 = 4 + C * e^{-k * 0}$

$3.69 = 4 + C * e^{0}$

$3.69 = 4 + C * 1$

$C = 3.69 - 4$

$C = -0.31$

Now I have initial temperature.

Now at t = 5,

$3.56 = 4.63 + (-0.31) * e^{-k * 5}$

$\frac{(3.56 - 4.63)}{(-0.31)} = e^{-5k}$

$3.4516 = e^{-5k}$

$\log_e(3.4516) = -5k$

$k = -0.2477$

Now I have the cooling/ heating constant

So now I can calculate the temperature of the product at t = 10 using this formula,

$T = Ta + C * e^{-kt}$

$T = 4.81 + (-0.31) * e^{(-(-0.2477)) * 5}$

$T = 3.74$

But if you see from the above table, the actual temperature of the product is 3.5, I have an error of -0.24

As the experiment is conducted in a controlled environment and using a very accurate thermometer, the calculated temperature of the product should be accurate. But I am not sure where am I going wrong. Can someone please to understand how can I calculate the temperature of the product at t = 10 accurately and also minimize the error in the calculation of the next temperature reading.

Comment: First, Newton’s Law of Cooling assumes constant ambient temperature. This is far from that. Note that the product cools, heats, cools, …. This is a far more complex modeling problem.

Comment: Thank for your reply @TedShifrin , but is my approach correct? Also if available, can u share some online documents for reference.

Comment: Something odd about this data is that the last few observations show that the product temperature is falling even though it is below the ambient temperature.    Anyway, I would take this data and find $\ln(T-T_a)$ at each period.  Then I would calculate a linear regression -- the y-intercept would correspond to $\ln C$ and the slope corresponds to $k$

Comment: As noted, the ambient temperature $T_a(t)$ depends on $t$ so that even if your differential equation is an adequate model your solution form $T=T_a+Ce^{-kt}$ cannot be valid. You could assume it is OK for the first 5 minutes to estimate $k$ then try and solve the differential equation numerically (Euler method maybe) and see how that fits. It may be though that you need to consider a fixed wall temperature, the air temp in the fridge and the product temperature.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @DougM . The data points which I share are just a sample. The original data fluctuates like a sine/cosine graph. So I don't think linear regression will work here

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty clear from the data that what's happening here is not Newtonian cooling. (It's not even cooling; the product is colder than its surroundings). You need to construct a sufficiently accurate model of what’s happening physically before you waste time on details of a mathematical model that doesn’t describe the physical situation even qualitatively.